# Informix: Limitation on Number of Items in IN Clause?

Tags: informix, where-clause

Is there a limitation to the number of items that can go into an IN clause in an Informix query (like the 1000 item limit in Oracle)?

We have a "large" (perhaps 2000) list of item numbers being passed through a web service for selection, so there isn't really any context available beyond the list of items.

Comment: I didn't know there was a limit on the number of values for an 'IN' statement!.. I have an app that does a SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE col_1 IN (SELECT col_2 FROM table_2).. table_2 has over 500K rows with unique col_2 values, thus the 'IN' is evaluating over 500K different values!..It works!..Also, why would you want to hardcode 1,000's of values into an 'IN' statement?.. 'IN (1,2,3,4...)' which translates into 'OR x = 1 OR x = 2... ???

Comment: @Frank: The limit on the number of values in the IN statement when written out in a comma-separated list of values is the length of an SQL statement. If you deal in positive integers (fewest overhead characters), you can have 10 single-digit numbers (20 bytes), 90 double-digit numbers (270 bytes), 900 triple-digit numbers (3,600 bytes), 9000 quad-digit numbers (45,000 bytes), and somewhere around 2750 quin-digit numbers, leaving a little space left for the rest of the SELECT, for about 12,750 distinct integer values in the list.  If you use placeholders, you can get to around 32,000 values.

Comment: @Frank: in the SELECT ... WHERE x IN(SELECT ...) construct, you don't create the list in the SELECT statement and there is no specific upper limit on the number of entries. However, the optimizer will probably try to treat the IN sub-query as a join condition.

Comment: @Jonathan: OK, that's something new learned today, although I would try to find a way to avoid having to manually enter a long array of values into an 'IN' statement.. So an 'IN' subquery is equivalent to a JOIN?.. I thought it translated into 'OR, OR, OR...' for similar related question see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338516/whats-the-fastest-way-obtain-the-maximum-value-of-a-column

Comment: @Frank: if you consider x IN (y) equivalent to a join with a one-column table containing the y values, you'll realize that the row in the 'multi-column' table(s) will be joined if it matches one of the rows, or '(x = y1 OR x = y2 OR ... x = yN)'.  I hadn't thought of it in those terms before, but I believe it is accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upper limit is imposed by the space that will be taken to create the IN list and the 64 KiB limit on statements.  You *can* typically get to several thousand smallish (6-7 digit) integers without much problem at the syntactic level.

However, you may find that the performance is not as good as creating a temporary table, inserting the several thousand values into that, and then writing the main query to join with that temporary table.

Comment: Thanks - I have seen this point a number of times.  However, I have yet to see an example of creating and populating the table.  Just use brute force?  If so, having a create plus 2000 inserts seems at least as inefficient as a single query.

Comment: Almost anything where you've a list of 2000 items gets a bit unwieldy, whether it is an IN clause or serial execution of one insert statement 2000 times.  Where do you collect the 2000 values from? If there's a SELECT statement to generate the list, then running the `SELECT ... INTO TEMP WhatEver` loads up the list. If some poor sod has to type 2000 values, then you won't notice the overhead of the inserts while the typing occurs. You might (or might not) notice the performance benefit after the final value is entered. As ever, YMMV and measurement is the key (and so is WITH NO LOG).

Comment: If the list is in a file on disk, consider whether an EXTERNAL table is available and a sensible option - which depends on the version of IDS that you have.

Comment: Unfortunately, the list is simply passed as a parameter to a web service.

Comment: If the list is passed as a parameter, there's a way to load that list into a temp or external table, then doing an 'IN' subquery on that list!

Comment: @Wonko: since its comming from a web service, perhaps extracting the parameters with 'xmlhttp=', OR  myConnection.Execute("Insert into sometable (somefield) values ( somevalue)")could accomplish the objective?

Comment: @Wonko: the first step is to see if the performance of the large IN list is satisfactory.  If so, there's no immediate need to optimize.  If it is unsatisfactory, then you have to get into a look at alternatives.  Since you've not mentioned your platform or version of IDS, we can't give specific advice very accurately; the answer for 11.70 might be different from the answer for 11.10, I suspect.  Also, does your list of values come over the wire as a single string or does it arrive in some array-based format?  That depends a lot on the development language, I suspect.

Comment: The data comes into a .NET-based web service as a List<int> (i.e. a list of integers).  The performance changes I've made is a many-times improvement over the previous implementation, and is thus "satisfactory."  However, I can forsee this being an issue down the road, and I also want to learn of any alternatives.